# FileNotFoundException While trying to copy the file from one directory to another

Tags: c#, .net, io, filenotfoundexception

I have some files (.txt, word, excel files) in "C:\ABC\Temp" and I want to move all the .txt files into "C:\ABC\Text", but I'm getting a `FileNotFoundException`.

Please find attached code.

```
static void Main()
{
    string sp = @"C:/ABC/Temp";
    string dp = @"C:/ABC/TextFiles";
    string[] fileList=Directory.GetFiles(sp);

    foreach(string file in fileList)
    {
        if (file.EndsWith(".txt"))
        { 
            File.Move(sp,dp);
        }
    }
}
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to move the entire directories with `File.Move`.

You have to specify the file name as well:

```
File.Move(file, Path.Combine(dp, Path.GetFileName(file)));
```

Comment: Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\AB
C\Temp\123.txt.txt'.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.File.InternalMove(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Bo
olean checkHost)
   at DemoOnIO.Class1.Main() in C:\Users\neerajkumar.p\AppData\Local\Temporary P
rojects\DemoOnIO\Class1.cs:line 19
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: I am not able to see Jony code. Don't know why ? can you please paste it for me @ Grant Winney